# React Router re-render route instead of re-render component

Tags: javascript, redux, react-router

I'm working on an app that is using React Router and I noticed that when my Redux store changes state that the router is re-rendering the component the current route refers to rather than re-rendering the route itself.

To illustrate the problem; I have implemented a `PrivateRoute` that checks if a user is currently logged in. In it's most basic form it looks something like this:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
  return <Route {...rest} render={(props) => {
    const state = store.getState()

    if (state.isAuthenticated) {
      return <Component {...props}/>
    }
    else {
      return <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login'}}/
    }
  }}/>
})
```

This works great since I can now say something like this:

```
<PrivateRoute path="/" component={HomePage}/>
```

However, I noticed that when the state of `isAuthenticated` changes that React Router is calling the `render` method on the `HomePage` component rather than that it re-renders the route. This means that the application will only do the authentication check when a user goes from some page to the home page but once on the home page, the check is no longer performed.

The only work around I have at the moment is to move the authentication check into the `render` function of the component (which is obviously not where it belongs).

How can I make React Router re-render the route rather than re-render the component the route refers to when the state changes?

Comment: You cannot connect the `PrivateRoute` to the authenticate state, instead of just getting the state from a store variable? I believe the rendering tree is just not getting aware of the changes inside the `PrivateRoute` based on some state change

Comment: I don't understand the first sentence/question of your comment. I suspect that React Router only calls the render method of the route once (when the route path is hit). After that it will not call render on the route again but only call render on the component returned by the route. I think this is a problem in the React Router. I'm looking for an elegant work around.

Comment: Mostly I suggested what you actually did in your answer, nl let the props propagate :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by using a Higher Order Component rather than implementing the authentication check in the route.

```
function withEnsureAuthentication(WrappedComponent) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    render() {
      if (this.props.store.isAuthenticated === false) {
        return <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login'}}/>
      }

      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props}/>
    }
  }
}
```

You can now use a normal `Route` but apply the `withEnsureAuthentication` to the component:

```
const HomePage = withEnsureAuthentication(Home)

<Route path="/home" component={HomePage}/>
```